# 403 error on opening truecaller in selenium on AWS Ubuntu instance

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, selenium, amazon-web-services, phantomjs

I am very new to selenium. I am trying to access [truecaller (http://www.truecaller.com)
I have written the following code:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()

driver= webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.truecaller.com/")
print driver.page_source

driver.close()
display.stop()
```

Running the script on AWS machine with Ubuntu instance returns **403**.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head></head>
  <body>403</body>
</html>
```

Same script runs fine in my Ubuntu Machine. I tried everything including [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), but I am unable to figure out the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like they have blocked the ip address of AWS servers, i am facing the same issue on AWS where as its working from one of the Azure VM